# IComparer<T> and generic type method issue

Tags: c#, generics

Here is the problem, I have to write method which is generic type, and can only be used by types which handle IComparer interface, in addition my method need to take T array and IComparer as parameter. Method should return maximum value from criteria specified by IComparer. I've written test class with basic implementation of IComparable and IComparer(code below).

```
public class TestClass : IComparable<TestClass>
{
    public int CompareTo(TestClass other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
public class Nested : IComparer<TestClass>
{
    IComparer<TestClass> criteria;

    public int Compare(TestClass x, TestClass y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Nested x = new Nested();
        TestClass[] tab = { new TestClass() };
        Tools.ElementsMax<TestClass>(tab, x);

    }
```

When i try to test out method i get this error:

> Blockquote Error  CS0311  The type 'x.TestClass' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Tools.ElementsMax(T[], IComparer)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'x.TestClass' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer'.

I don't understand why exactly I'm getting this error, I was really sure that it should work that way, but surprisingly it didn't.

Comment: `Tools.ElementsMax` is where it's erroring, but you havne't included that code.

Comment: Ah, yeah I haven't included it by accident, sorry. Here is the method.


`public static T ElementsMax<T>(T[] arrayParameter, IComparer<T> criteria) where T : IComparer<T>
        {

            return arrayParameter[1];
            
        }`

Comment: @banneh I guessed it right - your method does have a wrong constraint in its signature :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to write method which is generic type, and can only be used by types which handle `IComparer` interface, in addition my method need to take `T` array and `IComparer` as parameter.

You probably meant "which handle `IComparable` interface", not `IComparer`. From your error message it appears that your `ElementsMax` method is coded exactly the way you described it in English, i.e.

```
public static T ElementsMax<T>(T[] data, IComparer<T> c) where T : IComparer<T>
//                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This, however, is incorrect: you should constraint `T` to be `IComparable<T>` instead:

```
public static T ElementsMax<T>(T[] data, IComparer<T> c) where T : IComparable<T>
//                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for quick anwser, but I meant IComparer interface as it's one of given tasks, from our professor and it's clearly described that it should handle IComparer interface. Is there any possible soultion to do it that way?

Comment: @banneh Ask your professor if he's made a typo; I am certain that he did. `IComparer<T>` makes no sense in there, while `IComparable<T>` makes perfect sense.

Comment: For me `IComparer<T>` didn't make sense also but as far as I'm concerned the method is made to be used in class and return the maximum value based on one of the criterias given in `IComparer`, ex. name lenght or birth year in class, that's where `IComparer` makes sense to me .

Comment: @banneh On the other hand, taking `IComparer<T>` separately makes it possible to drop all constraints on `T`, i.e. to write `public static T ElementsMax<T>(T[] data, IComparer<T> c)` without a `where` clause.

Comment: @dasblinkenlinght Yes, I agree 100%, but I dont excatly understand why I'm not getting that error when removing `where` clause but with it included with constraint `where T: IComparable<T>` I'm getting error listed at the top of subject?

Comment: @banneh The error says that your `TestClass` does not satisfy the condition from the `where` clause. When you remove the `where` clause, there is nothing to satisfy, so the error goes away.